# Truncated adjective まっすぐ

Tags: syntax

I have a sentence in a book that goes like 甘い匂いのする**まっきいろ**な花です。It is a kids book, so everything is in kana. I'm having trouble figuring out the bolded part. It talks about a dandelion in the context, so I assume that きいろ is 黄色(yellow), what is this (まっ) then?

Google suggests that it might be following 甘い匂いのする**真っ黄色**な花です。and translates this (真っ) part as "straight". Can someone explain how this truncation happens?

Also, where to look up the grammar for "のする"?

Comment: The `甘い匂いのする` could also be written as `甘い匂いがする`.  Check [this topic](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/4346/78) for info on when `が` can be replaced with `の`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

まっ◯◯ is indeed 真っ, but it does not exactly mean straight. It can mean straight when you use it as 真っ直ぐ, but that's because of the meaning of すぐ. 真っ [emphasizes the word that it's connected to](http://www.weblio.jp/content/%E7%9C%9F%E3%81%A3). If you look at the meaning of 真 by itself, like "true," then it's a little clearer. So 真っすぐ means that it's "really" straight. まっきいろ would be "really" yellow, or like a pure yellow. It connects to some other words similarly, like 真{ま}っ赤{か}, 真{ま}っ裸{ぱだか}, 真{ま}っ白{しろ}い, etc.

The issue of の is a separate issue, but you should be able to find it in most grammar references, as well as in some questions on this site, like [here](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/9922/function-of-%E3%81%AE-in-these-phrases) and in the other questions linked in it.

Comment: So, the translation would be "It is a really yellow flower that smells sweet"?

Comment: yes, something like that

Comment: @ssb:  Does 'ssb' stand for "Super Smash Bros."?  Cause that's all I can think about when I reading your name.

Comment: it did back when i crated my first 'serious' online name when I was like 11 ('SSB' was part of it), and it just kind of stuck around because everyone referred to me as ssb. Nowadays I don't attach that meaning to it but etymologically, yes indeed.

Comment: And 真っ青 is まっさお (sic.), which is really not intuitive...