# Interpretation of のする

Tags: grammar

> 俺は**いい匂いのするハンカチ**で、軽く触れる程度に汗を拭いた。/ using the handkerchief with a nice smell....

Also found

> 妹は何でも姉のするようにした / The younger sister behaved [did everything] just as her older sister did.

When would one choose to use this structure? ie, compared to いい匂いをしているハンカチ edit: いい匂いをしたハンカチ

edit: this is more in regards to する as a descriptor rather than のｖｓが　within clauses.

thanks

Comment: Possible dupe: [What does する mean when it does not mean “do”?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/2289/9831)

Comment: See also: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/17854/9831・https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/11084/9831・https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/12825/9831

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> いい匂い**のする**ハンカチで、
>
> 何でも姉**のする**ようにした

You can also switch these の to が. It's the way to indicate the theme of the verb *in a modifying phrase or clause*. を doesn't work for these.

Once seeing 匂いをする and 何でも姉をする don't work, いい匂いをしているハンカチ too much sounds as though the handkerchief is performing a smell, while いい匂い**をさせた**ハンカチ works fine.

I've come to notice that the verb forms **ている** and **した** should be being used as ***adjectives***, and it can take the subject and make a non-finite (tiny) clause.

Still, as a caution, when it's with する, いい匂いをするハンカチ sounds as though the hankerchief performs a smell, and 何でも姉をするようにした is a very unusual thing to say and has only the sense of 'perform (a stereotype)' and no sense of 'do as (a particular someone does)'.

I think I can take いい匂いをしているお弁当箱{べんとうばこ} or いい匂いをしているジャスミンの花 all right, but *you can always choose to say* いい匂い**の**しているお弁当箱 or いい匂い**を漂{ただよ}わせている**ジャスミンの花.

Not to mention, the expressions like 姉をした and 姉をしている can't be used as an adjectives.

---

You can say any of these without making much difference in meaning:

> いい匂いの[が]しているハンカチ
>   何でも姉の[が]しているようにした
>
> いい匂いの[が]したハンカチ
>   何でも姉の[が]したようにした。

Just た starts to assume the sense of the past, I think it's because of の・が. They are no problem, but are better to be used when the sense of the past is needed such as when examining several handkerchieves.

Comment: i meant it as いい匂いをしたハンカチ woops, is there any difference in that regard?

Comment: It's 匂いがする to me, and never 匂いをする to me. いい匂いをしたハンカチ does not sound so bad.

Comment: ok thanks! i guess using する as "to have _ property" always felt a bit awkward.

Comment: @charu Could you tell me why いい匂いをしたハンカチ works? Is it something like because 匂いをした becomes an adjective or something? We say 声がする, but not 声をする, but we can say きれいな声をした人

Comment: It's just something i remember from tobira, either A は B をしている、or A をした B.  I know about の typically  replacing　が in relative clauses but that didn't pop into my head when i read  のする  since there wasn't any actual "action";  that and it was different than the をした structure, which was the only thing i knew up to now.

Comment: Thanks, charu. We would say 怖い声をする to mean someone make an effort to sound scary, but we don't say 声をする in place of 声がする; this means you hear someon's voice. I think 匂いをする doesn't work because ...even a skunk won't be described as performing a smell..